# JSON object has data but still says undefined

Tags: json

This is my json data.I can access all the key's values as ._id .price but not retailer and retailer_slug. I tried a lot I don't know what is that I am doing wrong

```
{ _id: 5b8d60136b4a6a2060f67707,
  product_upc: '00019200771825',
  price: '$5.49',
  retailer: 'wal_retailer',
  retailer_slug: 1,
  product_url: 'https://www.walgreens.com/store/c/lysol-4-in-1-disinfecting-wipes-citrus/ID=prod3471375-product',
  createdAt: 2018-09-03T16:28:10.298Z }
```

I need help as this is the unique kind of scenario I am stuck into.

Comment: I tried pasting this JSON into my dev console and it's invalid. You need quotes on _id and createdAt attributes

Comment: I finally got the solution. It was my cache that was creating issue. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code you are using to get the json info to help you.